# Column size issue : read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe that has 4 columns. I have to convert this dataframe to csv for working in my local computer. when I convert dataframe to csv I have only one column:

```
df = pd.read_csv("final.csv")
print df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 20479 entries, 0 to 20478
Data columns (total 1 columns)
```

How can I convert this csv to dataframe with 4 columns?

Comment: How do you export your df to csv? using what command?

Comment: Seems like a problem with separators, you are probably exporting with non-default kind of separator and importing with default one.

Comment: @MichaelO. Thans, sep="\t" solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Question is inconcise. Are you aiming to write a pandas dataframe object to a csv file, or create a dataframe object from an existing csv file?

[Pandas Dataframe to CSV](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) this link should be sufficient to write a df to a csv file, and vice versa listed here [Dataframe from CSV](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html).

A csv file (comma separated values) is separated by commas so make sure the separator is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

When you read in your dataframe, you might have to explicitly state what type of separator is being used. I would open the csv in a text editor and see what the separator is. If, for example, the separator used was "|", I would use the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('final.csv', sep='|')
```

Then, to save to a .csv the code should be as simple as:

```
df.to_csv('path/to/file/csvFileName.csv', index=False)
```

I would recommend using index=False like I did, otherwise the pandas index will be included as a column in your csv file. Cheers.